How to measure the velocity of a body "directly"? Is it possible?
I know that by making length and time measurements we can sometimes get a law for the movement and then calculate the velocity using calculus (it's the derivative with relation to time of the position function). So we obtained the velocity from a calculation involving other physical quantities we measured, i.e. an indirect measurement. I would like to know if it's possible to measure velocity directly by other experiments. Does this makes sense? I think it's not possible, but I'm not sure (how do we compare velocities in an experiment like we compare lenghts with lenghts, for example?). I don't know, maybe there is some law relating velocity and other physical quatities that could be of use. Sorry, if this doesn't make sense, I tried my best..

Velocity is defined as rate of change of position w.r.t. time. If you’re not allowed to measure either of those things (or anything else so “indirect”), you can’t measure velocity.

a monostatic doppler radar measures line of sight velocity by the frequency shift of the reflected wave (a bistatic radar measures another projected component of the velocity vector), this is about as direct measurement as one can give sense to that expression "direct measurement".

The idea of “direct measurement” is not a useful concept as far as I can tell

I am a layman in physics. I first read "direct measurement" in "The first direct measurement of gravitational waves was performed by the advanced Laser Interferometer Gravitational-Wave Observatory (LIGO) in 2015." https://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/LISA/Measuring_gravitational_waves

If LIGO is considered a direct measurement then your length and time measurements would be a direct measurement of velocity. I cannot think of any measurement that would be indirect with that as a standard. So yes, a useless concept. Useful descriptions of measurements include “accurate”, “precise”, “expensive”, etc.

If we could produce an object that always had the same speed, then we could measure the speed of other objects relative to it, and the units of speed would be in units of the velocity of such an object (call the units whatever name you want).
For instance, you could build a speed measuring device consisting of the object bouncing back and forth between two walls. If you could miniaturize such device, and count how many times the object bounces as another object passes by in between those same two walls, then you would be measuring velocity directly, by measuring how many times your object bounced as the object being measured covers the space between the two walls (the speed of the bouncing object need to be way larger than that of the moving one).
Such an object with a constant speed actually exists: light.  It is not practical nor useful, I believe, to build such a measuring device, but it is theoretically possible.
Such a device would allow you to calculate time as a derived, rather than fundamental quantity, as $t=x/v$, without using any clocks.

You could use something involving Doppler's effect. You emit a wave, and measure the frequency of the reflected wave, and then calculate using Doppler effect. That is how police radar guns are used to detect speeding cars.

But you are measuring the frequency, and use it to calculate the velocity.

@PatoGalmarini, Are you even measuring frequency? You're counting signal edges and comparing them to a known time interval, then displaying a number on a screen then photons reach your eyes and your brain interprets them as an image of the screen and then further interprets that as a "measurement"...Philosophically can we ever measure anything at all? (Or should we actually use the word measurement to means something sensible and useful like Andy did in this answer?)

@ThePhoton I agree, the issue is really deeper, and you are also assuming that this standards do not change as you move around, and everything is loaded with theory behind. I was tempted to answer that way first. Maybe you should add this valid view as an answer.

It's worse than you think. You can't even measure length or time "directly" - you can only measure them by comparison with a standard length or a standard time interval. And even then, you can only measure them approximately - I measure something to be $1.36$ metres long, but this really means its actual length is somewhere between $1.355$ metres and $1.365$ metres.
The only things that you can measure "directly" are things that come in discrete units, so you can count them. I know that there are exactly $3$ eggs in my fridge, but I only know that there is approximately $1$ litre of milk.
